# Get count from make-count scheme

Tags: scheme, procedure

```
Scheme> (define make-counter
            (lambda ()
               (let ((count 0))
                  (lambda ()
                     (set! count (+ count 1))
                     count)))


Scheme> (define c1 (make-counter))
C1

Scheme> (c1)
1
Scheme> (c1)
2
Scheme> (c1)
3
```

How do I make a procedure that takes the "count" counter out of c1?
I've tried

```
(define get-count
(lambda (q)
  (q)))
```

But this only makes it runs the procedure, not take the count variable out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is SICP style solution:

```
(define make-counter
  (lambda ()
    (let ((count 0))
      (lambda message
        (unless (equal? message '(get))
          (set! count (+ count 1)))
        count))))
```

Example:

```
> (define c (make-counter))        
> (c)
1
> (c)
2
> (c 'get)
2
> (c 'get)
2
> (c)
3
> (c 'get)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create a separate procedure to extract the count. Here's how you might do it:

```
(define (make-counter)
  (let ((count 0))
    (values (lambda ()
              (set! count (+ count 1))
              count)
            (lambda ()
              count))))
```

Here, we are returning two procedures: the first one is exactly the same as before, and the second one returns the count directly.

Usage example:

```
> (define-values (inc-count get-count) (make-counter))
> (inc-count)
1
> (inc-count)
2
> (inc-count)
3
> (get-count)
3
```

Note that this is different from extracting the value of a closed-over variable in a given procedure's lexical environment, which is what I believe your question is asking about. There is no standard way in Scheme to achieve such a thing.